# Cannot start my own program pressing super+num keybinding or by clicking on icon placed in dock

Tags: dock, desktop-icons

I would like to run an application with switch-to-application keybinding (SUPER+0..9)

Application is not installed with snap or ubuntu repository (apt install). sh file is just placed in my home directory.

I know how to create a .desktop file (/usr/share/applications/my_program.desktop) I know how to 'allow launching' and how to add a new icon to the dock

but somehow my program does not start from the dock (with Super+2 or with mouse click)

[image]

ps. double-clicking on my_program.desktop file when this file is placed on Home/Desktop runs program correctly

[image]

Comment: I tried the same on Zorin OS 16 and works as expected.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using. It sounds like you are describing the Ubuntu Unity desktop interface. Ubuntu moved to the Gnome desktop as default a few years ago. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1364474/edit) and add the information about your version of Ubuntu and the desktop environment (Unity or Gnome) you are using.

Comment: Unity? :) It's Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome)

Comment: Probably you can install Unity by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop` and retry from there.

Comment: Hi, I do not want to install 'unit' - do not know why you are suggesting me this step. Anyways - I moved to Zorin. Thanks